# Javascript errors in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me correct the mistake in javascript, it doesn't work in IE, i just can't understand what is the problem here:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".image2").click(function() {var image = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('#image2').hide();
        $('#image2').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#image2').html('<embed height="253" width="440" wmode="transparent" src="' + image + '"></embed>');
        var image2 = $('#image2 embed').attr('src');
        $("#thumb2 a img").removeClass("open");
        $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image2 + "'] img").addClass("open");
        return false;
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var image3 = $('#image2 embed').attr('src');
        $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image3 + "'] img").addClass("open");

        var n = $('#news_list');    
        n.find('.list_news a').css({opacity: 0.5}).hover(
            function() { $(this).css({opacity: 1}); },
            function() { $(this).css({opacity: 0.7}); }
        );
        n.hover(
            function() { $(this).find('a').css({opacity: 0.7}); },
            function() { $(this).find('a').css({opacity: 0.5}); }
        );
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.image').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var imagePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var newImg = new Image;
        newImg.src = imagePath;
        newImg.onload = function(){
            $('#big_picture').hide();
            $('#big_picture').attr('src', imagePath);
            $('#big_picture').fadeIn('slow');
        };
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(".dropdown a").each(function() {
        if(this.href == window.location) 
        $(this).addClass("open");
        });

        $('.slider_fade').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade',
        timeout: 7000,
        });
    });
    $('.upper_menu_link').attr('target', '_blank');

    var message="";
    function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}}
    function clickNS(e) {if 
    (document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
    if (e.which==2) {
    (message);
    return false;}}}
    if (document.layers) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS;
    }else{
    document.onmouseup=clickNS;
    document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;
    }
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false");

        $('.urun_div').corner("round 20px");
```

Comment: Could you clarify "doesn't work" please. What doesn't work? What error messages do you receive?

Comment: Extra comma after `timeout: 7000`??

Comment: @Marko Excellent spot -- I'm sure that's the reason.

Comment: @Marko Dumic: exactly! extra comma after timeout )) thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marko: Please make your comment an answer.  Comments are typically reserved for questions back to the OP... never mind that your comment is the right answer and it can't be accepted as the answer...

Comment: @venom seriously dude, your code looks messy... number of `.ready()` functions(though it doesn't matter) .. may be an online example like a demo to ur problem helps the community in solving this problem. Have a Good Day !

Comment: @Marko's comma-guru! He deserved an accepted answer! @Marko, don't be shy to answer this question, not just comment it!

Comment: Thanks guys. I posted an answer, I hope a bit more informative than the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma after `timeout: 7000` is the problem.

More info on [Internet Explorer's trailing comma woes](http://brajesh.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/internet-explorers-trailing-comma-woes/).

Sometimes I search my code for these using regular expressions similar to those in the previous link whenever my code fails in IE but works in other browsers.

Also, the [Javascript Lint](http://www.jslint.com/) can be of massive help with mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Internet Explorer come with a passable set of developer tools (accessed by pressing F12), if you use these they will tell you things like what line number your error occurred on, what type of error it was (syntax, NaN, undefined etc).